# Almost Perfect Accuracy in Both Training and Validation Sets, but Nothing Showed Up in All But One of the Classes' Saliency Map

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

My convolutional neural network (with 5 layers: first 3 are Conv2D, last 2 are FC's) to classify four different classes of protein images resulted in very high accuracies and low losses in both training and validation datasets (>0.99 for accuracies and <0.01 for losses).

Nevertheless, when I plotted the saliency maps to determine the important features for each class, the saliency maps of the first three were empty, i.e., saliency scores were all zeros or close to zero. The saliency map of the fourth class, however, showed numerous dots (the highest saliency was 1.0) at the expected pixels/regions.

So my question is whether I was doing something wrong or the final saliency map is the saliency map for the whole classification? Can it also be due to the fact that my model was too simple or not run long enough (50 epochs for now)?

Comment: What method are you using to calculate the saliency maps?

Comment: What is a saliency map=

Comment: I used vanilla gradient @tchainzzz

Comment: Does your dataset has class imbalance problem? Did you check that model predicts the proportion of classess similar to the proportion in training set?